# Changing ticker label of axis in bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I have created a bokeh plot. But ticker of y axis is showing values in power of 10. As shown [image: here]

how can I change it to values like 20000,40000,60000,80000 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `use_scientific`:

```
fig = figure()
x = np.linspace(0, 100)
fig.line(x, x**4)
yaxis = fig.yaxis[0]
yaxis.formatter.use_scientific = False
show(fig)
```